# How did the glove save Tony Stark?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-3

After Tony Stark was caught in debris under the sea, Jarvis detaches the glove from the suit and takes the hand of Tony (by controlling the glove), pulling him out of his death trap.

How is this explained? We can assume the glove has a thruster on its back end (to be able to fly to Tony when needed), but how it can fly in reverse?

Answer (score 11):

All parts of Iron Man's suit can act like an independent robot. So it's possible for Jarvis to control one body part (glove) to act differently than the other Iron Man parts. And it is never mentioned that the new Iron Man suit can only be summoned to/by Tony. If you remember, he sent the suit to Pepper to protect her. So it seems possible to me.

Comment: As for propelling itself backwards, there's no reason to suggest that the individual pieces can't maneuver in every direction.

Comment: I can't see the reason why it couldn't just pull him out while still attached to him though. They probably just did it for the wow factor.

Comment: @atticae I don't understand why you would think it could pull him out while still attached. It looks like the little "thrusters" are on the interior surface of the glove, wouldn't they damage his skin, or even be unable to operate while attached to the rest of the suit?

Comment: @ghoppe Honestly I don't remember the exact details of the scene, would have to rewatch it. But you are probably right.

Comment: @ghoppe I'm about a year late to this party, but I've watched this movie regularly in the past. I don't think the thrusters could have been inside, because A) that makes them useless to the suit and B) the inside of the glove is facing *away* from Tony - to propel him upward, the boosters would have to be facing towards him.

Comment: @Nobby in fact we should assume that they can fly in all directions because they have to be able to fly onto his body when he's suiting up.

Comment: @ColorQuestor: A) "useless"? Autonomous assembly was one of the suit's primary features. Without omni-directional thrusting, that simply won't work, so I'm not seeing the "useless" aspect.